# Converting ruby array to javascript array not working properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am trying to convert a ruby array to javascript array in my rails application

```
@qs #=> [1, 4]
```

The javascript code is:

```
var js_array =  [<%= @qs.to_json %>];
var arrayLength = js_array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    alert(js_array[i]);
}
```

But I am getting the `arrayLength` as `1`. The alert message in the loop display `1,4` once.

I have tried converting the array to string array, but there is no difference:

```
var new_array = js_array.map(String);
```

**What I need**: I should be able to loop through the javascript array and alert each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `to_json` method returns a string that includes the array brackets. Therefore this should work:

```
var js_array =  <%= @qs.to_json %>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `@qs` array to `js_array` when using `Haml` template language

```
var js_array = #{@qs} ;
```

Code in `views`:

```
:javascript
  var js_array =  #{@qs};
  var arrayLength = js_array.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    alert(js_array[i]);
  }
```

`@qs = [1,2]` in controller.

Comment: I wanna why give me a minus, I have test my code and works like what you want.

Comment: It gives `SyntaxError: illegal character`. At `var js_array =  #{@qs};`

Comment: @jonsnow i have updated my answer, but it's really works fine for me ... :(

Comment: Looks like you are using Haml, but the OP uses the ERB template language. So your answer does not answer his question.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var js_array = <%= @arr %>
var arrayLength = js_array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    alert(js_array[i]);
}
</script>
```

In my controller

```
@arr = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: It works because this is a simple case. You can't just dump a Ruby variable in a javascript code without `to_json` or `escape_javascript`